# How i can get the right selector on Click?

Tags: jquery

i need your help.

i try to get the right selector when i click but the problem is its show all parent's div.

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="">element1</a> <span>span1</span> <br>
    <a href="">element10</a> <span>span10</span> <br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element2</a> <span>span2</span><br>
    <a href="">element20</a> <span>span20</span><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element3</a> <span>span3</span><br>
    <a href="">element30</a> <span>span30</span><br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element4</a> <span>span4</span><br>
    <a href="">element40</a> <span>span40</span><br>
</div>
```

JS code :

```
$('.item span').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(){

    // hide all span
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
    $(".item span").not($this).hide();

    // here is what I want to do
    $this.toggle();

});
```

exemple : 
http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/637/

I would like, when i click on "Element10", only span10 show and not span1 
Can you help me? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) at this context to ease your work,

```
var items = $('.item span').hide();
$('.item a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    items.not($(this).next('span').toggle()).hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/640/)

Comment: @AlainProfessional I just added a link to next in my post. Please read it. By the way Glad to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.item span').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.item span').hide();
    $(this).next('span').toggle();    
});
```